# Koa2 sends 404, though function works. What’s the deal?

Tags: javascript, koa2

I’ve got an API set up with Koa2 that sends a request to mailgun upon post to /contact with name, email, and message.
The email gets sent just fine but I get a 404 in the console client-side. Why would I be getting this behavior?

```
module.exports = {

/**
 *@api {post} /contact
 *@apiGroup Public
 * @apiName sendMail
 * @apiParam {String} [name] User needs to provide their name
 * @apiParam {String} [email] User needs to provide their email
 * @apiParam {String} [message] user needs to provide their message
 * @apiParamExample {String} Request Params :
 * {
 *  "name"  : "Cello",
 *  "email" : "yo@yo.ma,
 *  "message" : "you are so great"
 * }
 * @apiSuccess {Object} return value  A success or failure
 * @apiSuccessExample {json} Response:
 * {
 *  "result" : "success"
 *  "callback" : "Do something"
 * }
 * @apiExample {curl} Example usage:
 * curl -i http://localhost:4000/contact
 * @apiDescription Any user can submit contact
 * @apiHeader {String} Authorization  JWT Authorization header (optional)
 * @apiHeaderExample {json} Request Authorization Header
 * {
 *  "authorization" : "jkahdkjashdk324324342"
 * }
 */
async mail(ctx){
let {email, name, message} = ctx.request.body;

if (!email) {
    ctx.throw(400, 'please provide the email')
}
if (!name) {
    ctx.throw(400, 'please provide a name')
}
if (!message) {
    ctx.throw(400, 'please provide a message')
}
var api_key = 'key-xxxxxxxxxx';
var domain = 'mg.domain.com';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

var data = {
    from: name+'<'+email+'>',
    to: 'me@domain.com',
    subject: 'Contact Form',
    text: message
};

var result = mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

}
}

Comment: I think this may be because the mail function is async but the mailgun call doesn’t wait for the response from mailgun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the `async`-`await` pattern, your code should look like this:

```
async mail(ctx){

    ...

    var result = await mailgun.messages().send(data)
    console.log(body);
};
```

The missing part is the `await`. As - due to the docs - the `mailgun-js` module also implements promises, this should work (not tested).